# How to use variables in several files? Global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, global

(Sorry my english) 
There is a way to use a variable on whatever file i am using?
Like:

```
# Alpha
a = 5
import Beta
print(a)

# Beta
print(a)
a = 4
```

Output:

```
5
4
```

I know that i can do something like:

```
# Gamma (TMP)
a = 0

# Alpha
import Gamma as g
g.a = 5
import Beta
print(g.a)

# Beta
print(g.a)
g.a = 4
```

But well, this is only an example, my real-code is more complex and I don't want to have a file called tmp.py with a lot of variables equal (=) nothing ('',0,[],(),{},None, etc). 
I read a bit of global in documentation, but i am not sure what is that or how to use it, Could someone explain me how to use that?
Is something like this?

```
# Alpha
import global
global a
a = 5
import Beta
print(a)

# Beta
import global
global a
print(a)
a = 4
```

Have I must to put "import global" in all files? 
For each variable i have to do "global variable"? 
Can I do global "var1, var2, var3, etc" for multiple globals?
If i don't want "a" be a global anymore, What i have to do?

```
¿?
import global
global a
do_something()
not_more_global a
do something
```

Will "a" losse it's value or not?
Also, there is a way to do something like:

```
# Alpha
import Beta with "some_argument"

# Beta
print(argument)

Or

# Alpha
import Beta with a = 5

# Beta
print(a)
```

¿No?

**PD:** I use python 3.6 32-bits, windows 10 64-bits.

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of global state and functions that do things to that state, you need to start thinking in terms of functions that take input through arguments and communicate results with return values.

Comment: @user2357112 What??? Sorry, i am not very advanced. Could explain with a little example (examples are better than theory or me)? Are you talking about defs (functions)? How can i use them for that??

Comment: For your last thing: there is no “import with” statement. You could do something like:
`import Beta
Beta.a = 5`